# creating NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

You can create a NSMutableDictionary with:

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)]
```

and

```
[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:(NSDicitionary *)]
```

Is the only difference between the two that the first returns a autoreleased object?

Comment: Yes. And if you use ARC, there is no real difference.

Comment: Yes, i use ARC as well, just wanted to be sure. Thanks

Comment: You can create dictionaries in many other ways, these just copy other dictionary's. The `-copy` and `-mutableCopy` methods, for example

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Although you can just call `+ (id)dictionary` and `- (id)init` if you don't have an `NSDictionary` instance.

Under ARC a growing trend is to use `+ (id)new` as it is more succinct.